# How to serialize an object with a "File" inside

Tags: android, file, serialization

I have an object like this

```
public class Audio {

    private long creationTime;
    private String author;
    private int length;
    private File content;
}
```

Right now I'm manually writing to another file all the fields and then I append the content.
Is there a way to serialize this object in a simpler way?

**EDIT**

I know about writeObject and the Serializable interface.
The problem is that, using this way, it happened that the File was null after the deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

through `writeObject`. `File` implements `Serializable` . [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html) the doc

Comment: can you post the complete code? or at least Audio's initialiazation and where do you write it